# php preg_replace wont accept outside reference

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following function which as you can see, replaces certain characters in a string with the pattern, yet it only works when I enter in the pattern as a string like in the first commented out line.  I put an echo in there to test what was coming back and its as it should be so I dont know whats going on!  Has anyone any clues?

```
    private function check_string( $s )
    {
        //return preg_replace( '/[^a-z 0-9~%\.:_\\-()"]/i', '', $s );

        // a-z 0-9~%\.:_\\-()"
        echo $this->permitted_uri_chars;

        // /[^a-z 0-9~%\.:_\\-()"]/i
        $pattern = '/[^'. $this->permitted_uri_chars .']/i';    
        return preg_replace( $pattern, '', $s );            
    }
```

The error I get is

`Message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 18`

**ANSWER**

---

Thanks to Jason McCreary

`$pattern = '/[^'. preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '/') .']+/i';`

Comment: The hyphen should be escaped if not at the end for exaple [a-z0-9_-] here not require to be escaped but for [a-z0-9-_] should be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working in the first example because you properly escaped characters for both PHP and the Regular Expression. (i.e. `\\`).

When using a string, you have only escaped for PHP. So when you use this string in your Regular Expression it is no longer escaped.

This is demonstrated by the following example:

```
echo '/[^a-z 0-9~%\.:_\\-()"]/i';
// becomes: /[^a-z 0-9~%\.:_\-()"]/i
```

A few options would be:

- Double escape.
- Avoid the Regular Expression escaping by placing the dash at the end: `/[^a-z 0-9~%.:_()"-]/`
- Use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) if you're going to accept strings regular expression syntax.

**Note:** I'd encourage you to read about [escaping inside character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: ah hah! cool.. so would i need to double up on the backslashes then?

Comment: I'm writing for CodeIgniter so it wont be possible to tell everyone to move the `-` to the end.  I've tried `preg_quotes` it errors as well, also tried `str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $s)`... nothing working yet but at least I've got something to think about. Thank you

Comment: This is working `$pattern = '/[^'. preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '/') .']+/i';`